# Mockito Error when initializing instance variables from within a contructor

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I am writing the unit tests for a spring application using Mockito and following is the unit test for a service class.

service class:

```
@Service
class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{
    @Autowired
    private ExternalService externalService;

    MyServiceImpl () {
        int value = externalService.getValues();
    }


}
```

As you can notice I initialize an instance variable inside the constructor using a method from a service class called ExternalService which is Autowired.

test class:

```
public class LotteryServiceImplTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private MyServiceImpl myService;

    @Mock
    private ExternalService externalService;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetLotteryResult() {
        //test specific code
    }
}
```

When I run the test it gives an error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
    Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'value' of type 'MyServiceImpl'.
    You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
    However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : null
```

How can I create the mock service before injecting the test object when the  constructor of the test object depends on the mock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the way your are injecting and using the ExternalService dependency in your MyServiceImpl class. @Autowired is processed by a BeanPostProcessor () which runs after the bean has been instantiated.Hence the value of the externalService reference is only initialized after the constructor has run. So you cant use it in your constructor because at that point its still null;

You can fix this by moving this line int value = externalService.getValues(); from the constructor to your business method.

If you want to initialize value once at startup you can make use of a @PostConstruct initialization callback like so

```
@Service
class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{
    @Autowired
    private ExternalService externalService;
    private int value;

    MyServiceImpl () {

    }

    @PostConstruct
     public void initValue(){
        value = externalService.getValues();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to instantiate `MyServiceImpl` class and autowired `externalService` variable is definitely null in the following line in `MyServiceImpl` constructor

```
int value = externalService.getValues();
```

In order for Mockito to create a mock it has to call no arg constructor based on your post. So the result will be `NullPointerException`.

One of the best place to do this initialization is within `@Before`annotated method where you can call `externalService.getValues()` and set the `value` instance variable with a setter method.